# Not able to clear palette settings for Gedit terminal plugin in dconf-editor (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, gedit

I am trying to change the color of the embedded terminal plugin in Gedit (3.18) on my Ubuntu virtual machine. All solutions I have found online suggest clearing the palette settings in dconf-editor to do so, but mine is not letting me do that. Can you please help? [It's supposed to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbsOE.png), but mine looks like this and is giving me an error message when I try to clear the palette :([image: Mine :(]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value via the command line by issuing the command below.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.plugins.terminal.use-theme-colors false
```

Note: You may need root privilege to do it. If so, prefix the command with `sudo`.

**EDIT:**

Notice the dot before `use-theme-colors`.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.plugins.terminal use-theme-colors false
```

**EDIT:**

To change the palette color, you can try this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.plugins.terminal palette "PUT YOUR ARRAY OF PALLETE COLORS HERE"
```

For example:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.plugins.terminal palette "['#2E2E34343636', '#CCCC00000000', '#4E4E9A9A0606', '#C4C4A0A00000', '#34346565A4A4', '#757550507B7B', '#060698209A9A', '#D3D3D7D7CFCF', '#555557575353', '#EFEF29292929', '#8A8AE2E23434', '#FCFCE9E94F4F', '#72729F9FCFCF', '#ADAD7F7FA8A8', '#3434E2E2E2E2', '#EEEEEEEEECEC']"
```

**Note:**

- Palette color has 16 colors and each color name should be in hex format.
- To find out your palette color, you can `open your terminal > right click > profiles > profile preferences`. Go to tab `colors`. In the bottom, you can mix the color for your palette.
- Please notice the double quotes before and after the square bracket.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Does'nt work for me : not the right syntax, ans it for `use theme color` that I can deseable manually. Thanks.

Comment: @Tarass sorry for mistyped the command. I have edited it. Hope it works for you. :)

Comment: Syntax is correct. I want to change the palette argument, then I tried awith palette, it works syntaxally, can't get a void argument on palette.

Comment: @Tarass You can list your Gnome settings with this command:

`gsettings list-schemas`

If you want to filter the output, then pipe it with `grep` command. For example:

`gsettings list-schemas | grep org.gnome.gedit`

Once you find what you want to edit, you can list the key with the example command:

`gsettings list-keys org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser`

Then, you can check if the key is writable with the example command:

`gsettings writable org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser tree-view`

Comment: @Tarass Finally, you can get or set the value to the key with the example command: `gsettings get org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser tree-view`.

Or, you can set the existing value the the example command: `gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser tree-view false`.

You can match the example with your case. :)

Comment: @Tarass I have edited my answer which can be more suitable for you. Hope it helps you to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes and no ;-) Yes it puts palette argument at `[]` but as with dconf, but the final goal is to change colors in gedit embeded terminal that suppose to have an `empty` argument in palette. With `[]` it does'nt work. Still looking for a solution : http://askubuntu.com/questions/796297/gedit-embeded-terminal-color